# Exchange 2010 SP2 EWS API GetDelegates

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using Exchange 2010 SP2 EWS API to display delegates by employee.   It worked for all mailbox, except one mailbox..  For some reason, EWS API doesn't return this employee's delegates.  However, our Exchange admin were able to show the delegates from the UI and shell script.

Here is the code to return a list of delegates.
Mailbox mailbox = new Mailbox(email);
DelegateInformation result = service.GetDelegates(mailbox, true);

Is this the problem due to mailbox settings or something I did wrong calling API?

Comment: Permissions on the mailbox?

Comment: Is the response showing no delegates or are you getting an error? Your XML trace files would help debug.